# How can I exclude getters and setters in aspectJ?

Tags: java, aspectj, aop

I have a class aspectJ in my maven project whitch hepls me to show the Begin and the End of any called method in my project.
I try now to exclude all getters and setters.
I try modify this annotation:
 `@Around("execution(public * *(..))` 
by
 `@Around("execution(public * *(..) && !within(* set*(..))")`

But it doesn't whork and it gives me that in the consol:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.7:compile (default) on project spb-lceb: AJC compiler errors:
 [ERROR] error at @Around("execution(public * *(..) && !within(* set*(..))")
 Syntax error on token "execution(public * *(..) && !within(* set*(..))", ")" expected
```

Any idea

Comment: i resolve a part of this  issue (juste for setters) :
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && !execution(public void *set*(..))")

But for getters not yet , because i have some methods started by Get...()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's only a typo because you have a mising `)` at the end of the  execution call before the `&&` operator:

```
@Around("execution(public * *(..) && !within(* set*(..))")
```

Should be:

```
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && !within(* set*(..))")
```

Try it, that should do the trick.

And for the methods that begins with **Get** the best solution is to rename them to get rid of this conflict.

Comment: i did that and it works perfect and for the get i khnow that the only solution is to rename the methods that begins with Get

Comment: Great, yes it's the easiest way to avoid all the pain.

Comment: This **cannot** be the correct solution because `within(* set*(..)` will not even compile. This pointcut type needs a type signature, not a method signature.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted solution is clearly wrong because `within(* set*(..))` will not even compile. This pointcut type needs a type signature, not a method signature. Furthermore, it only tries to take care of setters, not getters as asked by the OP.

The correct solution is:

```java
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && !execution(* set*(..)) && !execution(* get*(..))")
```

By accepting the wrong solution the OP even irritated someone else trying the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48358673/1082681). This is why after such a long time I am writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
//package name to exclude
@Pointcut("execution(* com.aasif.dao.*.*(..))")
private void forDaoPackage() {}

//getter
@Pointcut("execution(* com.aasif.dao.*.get*(..))")
private void getter() {}

//setter
@Pointcut("execution(* com.aasif.dao.*.set*(..))")
private void setter() {}

//excluding getter and setter  method 
@Pointcut("forDaoPackage() && !(getter() || setter())")
private void forNoGetterSetter() {}


//applying to advice
@Before("forNoGetterSetter()")
public void excludingGetter() {
    System.out.println("performCloud()");
    }
```