# How to configure aspectj ignore getters and setters

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I have an aspect that currently works to capture all public method executions within my package.

I would like to modify that to exclude both setters and getters, so I tried that and these are the variants I tried:

This one works, but does obviously does not do anything for setters or getters.

```
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && !within(com.walterjwhite.logging..*)")
```

This does not compile:

```
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && !within(* set*(..))")
```

This compiles, but doesn't prevent capturing setters/getters:

```
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && !execution(* set*(..))")
```

I also came across this post as a reference, but that didn't work.  I get compilation errors when trying to compile the aspect.

[How can I exclude getters and setters in aspectJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297095/how-can-i-exclude-getters-and-setters-in-aspectj)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one does not compile because `within()` needs a type signature, not a method signature. The answer you are referring to is just plain wrong, I have no idea why it was accepted. I just wrote [a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48361530/1082681) in order to correct that false information.

Your last try is basically right, but only ignores setters, not getters. Try this:

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  private int id;
  private String name;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Doing something");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application = new Application();
    application.setId(11);
    application.setName("John Doe");
    application.doSomething();
    System.out.println(application.getId() + " - " + application.getName());
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Around("execution(public * *(..)) && !execution(void set*(*)) && !execution(!void get*())")
  public Object myAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[]))
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())
Doing something
11 - John Doe
```

Please note that

- if you have getters for boolean values like `isActive()` and also want to ignore them, you have to extend the pointcut by `&& !execution(boolean is*())`.
- those kinds of pointcuts with name patterns are always just heuristics, so beware of method names such as `getaway`, `settleConflict`, `isolate`. They would also be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, for brevity, I left the getter part out, once I got setters working, it should be cake to add getters.  Yes, I'll add is, and yes, since this is already a heuristic, I am thinking about how to best enforce naming patterns for the rest of my code to avoid this conflict.  Since I started with using aspectj for logging, writing code in outline form makes logging easy to interpret and I write virtually no log statements.  This works, thank you very much.

Comment: Please note that I improved the pointcut a little bit into `!execution(void set*(*)) && !execution(!void get*())`, i.e. I enforce that the setter has void return type and exactly one parameter, the getter has non-void return type and no parameters. Similarly `!execution(boolean is*())` enforces that a boolean value be returned. This makes the heuristics a bit more precise and you will have fewer false positives.

Comment: Another idea: Instead of enforcing naming patterns you can regularly scan your code base for problematic signatures and either rename the methods or, if the names make sense, add a marker annotation such as `@Loggable` to them and extending the pointcut by `|| @annotation(my.package.Loggable)` in order to include them in the logging anyway.

Comment: Yes, I have both a Loggable and NonLoggable annotation.  The project is open source, I will push to git shortly once it is stabilized.